# Ruby on Rails, paste text without label

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I am using `<%= f.label :remember_me %>` to paste the text of the remember tag (multilingual support), but this is messing with my css. Is there another way I can paste `:remember_me` without the label tags (just as plain text)? Sorry for the simple and newbie question.

Comment: Can you give more context? Do you just want the value of `remember_me`? If so then you can just do `@user.remember_me` or whatever object it is.  Honestly its not very clear what you're asking

Comment: I am using Devise (gem), and in the login form, there is a remember me button. I have a checkbox, and then `<%= f.label :remember_me %>`. The <label> attribute is making it a little off center (http://screencloud.net/v/p5Up). Is there a way to paste the value of `:remember_me` without the label tags?

Comment: @nahtnam Don't use the label tag?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, thats what I want to do, but then I dont know how to render the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<%= f.object.class.human_attribute_name :remember_me %>
```

This will automatically return i18ned attribute name.

Comment: It will fail, if there won't be an object for the form.

Comment: Do I have to fill in something for `object`? I havent done so, and it works but if I need to fill something there, please let me know.

Comment: @marvelousNinja - Then f.label wouldn't translate it neither.

Comment: @nahtnam - `f.object` returns active record model you associated with a form. It might be nil in some rare cases (when using form_tag or when run `form_for :object` (symbol instead of object). So no need to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove this label tag and replace it by anything you like. All that matters for proper functioning - is the checkbox itself. To get the actual value of field you can do the following:

```
<p><%= f.object.try(:remember_me)  %></p>
```

Hope it helps.